# Mac Pro graphics card upgrade questions

Tags: display, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro Mid 2010 that since about a week ago only displays a blank white screen after rebooting. It doesn’t respond to various startup options. My reseller advised my to replace the original ATI Radeon 5870 graphics card.

I installed a new Sapphire Pulse RX 580 (so that I can later upgrade the Mac OS from 10.13.6 to 10.15) plus new cable, but see nothing at all on the monitor. I assume the bios doesn’t recognize the card as I could not install any software. How can I solve this?

Could I temporarily install an ATI Radeon 5770 that has been used in a PC just to install software for the RX 580?

Any alternatives?

Comment: First of all, some graphics cards aren't supported on Mac computers. In this case, the best solution is to contact Apple so that they can recommend what to do. If you have AppleCare, tampering with the machine by yourself can void your AppleCare.

Comment: The Sapphire Pulse is compatible, but you *must* flash the video BIOS.  Until you do that, it's going to show nothing on the screen.  See the link referenced.  As far as the 5570 used in the PC, it's the same issue...if it's not flashed, it won't work.

Comment: A non-flashed card will eventually show picture, once you reach Finder. idk what happens if you have file vault or need to actually sign in, all the pros here go straight to desktop, no sign in req'd. AMD cards shouldn't need 3rd party drivers, only NVidia. Do make sure to reset the SMC.  I recently put an NVidia in one of the machines here & also couldn't wake the screen. I installed the web-drivers over Apple Remote Desktop, which did show picture. btw, no new GPU will enable you to run Catalina, unless you use the dosdude patcher, Mojave is the limit, strictly.

Comment: Voting to reopen this, as the question doesn't ask about flashing & should not require flashing to solve. [The puter may be dead, who knows yet;) but the card itself not being flashed is not the sole cause or cure.]

Comment: I read at xlr8yourmac.com that FileVault could be the issue. 

http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/archives/feb18/RadeonRX-580_MacPro.html#RadeonRX_580_8GB_MacPro

To be honest, I can’t remember whether FileVault is turned on or not, but it could be case. Without a working card, I can’t check. 

I have dropped the idea of buying a used PC version Mac HD5770, cheap but too risky. 

At this moment I am considering to buy a refurbished  HD5870 so that I can use the machine again.

Comment: Should that work, then I still run the risk of that used card breaking down, plus I still can’t upgrade to 10.15. Therefore I am considering to buy a flashed RX580 from macvidcards.com. Any thoughts?

Comment: Filevault could be a possibility. Have you tried signing in 'blind'? Other than that, yup, go for a flashed one, or an old GT120 if you can find a cheap one, just till you find out why it's not getting to the desktop. MacVidsCards are supposed to be good, but I've never actually bought from them. I got an HD7950 a few years back on eBay from some random self-flasher in Aus. [I'm UK]. The other Pros mainly use OEM HD5770s from Apple.